# Interface vs. concrete object return value question

Tags: c#

So I am trying to understand this sample code from Lynda.com without explanation.

IScore.cs

```
internal interface IScore
{
    float Score { get; set; }
    float MaximumScore { get; set; }
}
```

ScoreEntity.cs

```
internal class ScoreEntity : IScore
{
    public float Score { get; set; }
    public float MaximumScore { get;set;}
}
```

ScoreUtility.cs

```
internal class ScoreUtility
{
    public static IScore BestOfTwo(IScore as1, IScore as2)
    {
        var score1 = as1.Score / as1.MaximumScore;
        var score2 = as2.Score / as2.MaximumScore;

        if (score1 > score2)
            return as1;
        else 
            return as2;
    }
}
```

Calling code:

```
 var ret = ScoreUtility.BestOfTwo(new ScoreEntity() { Score = 10, MaximumScore= 4}, 
            new ScoreEntity() {Score = 10, MaximumScore = 6});
 return;
```

My question is, in the ScoreUtility, what's really the benefit of using the interface type as return type in the method and argument type in the parameters, vs. just using ScoreEntity  for the return and parameters, since the method itself returns a concrete object? Is this just to make the code looked 'smart'?

Comment: Its all about SOLID principles. You can google it and there is a lot of exciting articles available from which you can learn how to write effective codes

Comment: Solid or design principles I've read, that a developer should always program to an interface, so basically saying interface should always be there, but in the code I've pasted, I could just use a class instead of interface in the return type and arguments and it won't matter to the method code, so what's really the underlying objective of the interface usage here?

Comment: In this example, using interfaces instead of concrete class, it looks to me indeed as a bit overengineered. Your type has just two properties. I can't think of many other exciting impementations than the one you provieded

Comment: @Mohi That's what you hear a lot, but none of the SOLID principles actually touch on this. This isn't dependency inversion (like using a DB interface instead of a concrete class). This is a POCO. Use abstraction where abstraction pays for itself. After all, the only problem you can't "solve" with abstraction is too much abstraction :P

Comment: @Mohi Yeah, and the problem is that it just trains you to put interfaces everywhere, just in case. And then those interfaces cover all of the methods of the object, and you're violating interface segregation. And then you use those abstractions poorly (because they're poor themselves), and violate LSP. Even the stupidest example on how to use interfaces should use an abstraction that _is useful_ ; otherwise what are you really learning? It's not like creating an interface that covers the whole object is a skill. Heck, we had plenty of fun with that in the good old "Animal<-Cat, Animal<-Dog" :D

Comment: @Luaan Yep, `1 CLS:PRINT"GOOD OLD GWBASIC :D":GOTO 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any class that implements the `IScore` interface can be passed into the ScoreUtility method.

Perhaps there's a reason to implement another `ScoreEntity` class, like wanting to add a name seen in `NamedScoreEntity` :

```cs
internal class NamedScoreEntity: IScore
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public float Score { get; set; }
    public float MaximumScore { get;set;}
}
```

If that's the case, then you can still use your utility methods on the new classes because of the contract the `IScore` interface enforces.

In this case, you could now compare the score between an un-named score object to a score object that also has a name.

Similarly, returning `IScore` allows the method to remain flexible enough to be used on multiple object types, and you can easily cast the returned type when you need to.

Comment: You don't need an interface for that: `internal class NamedScoreEntity : ScoreEntity { public string Name {get;set;} }`

Comment: Yea, I originally wrote it out as inheriting the `ScoreEntity`, but thought it would answer the question better by just implementing the interface.

Answer (score 0):

Given this declaration

```
public static IScore BestOfTwo(IScore as1, IScore as2)
```

The method does not know (or care) about the concrete types of as1 and as2. They *may* be ScoreEntity, or may be something entirely different. All it knows is that they implement IScore.

So if the method was to return a concrete type, then you have effectively limited the as1 and as2 parameters to being ScoreEntity, and have reduced its flexibility.

The only way you could guarantee that the method wouldn't fail would be to rewrite it as

```
public static ScoreEntity BestOfTwo(ScoreEntity as1, ScoreEntity as2)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the posted code there is very little benefit, and I would argue that the interface should be removed. I would also argue that the comparison logic probably should be part of the object, or possibly an implementation of [`IComparer<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icomparer-1?view=net-6.0).

Interfaces are most useful when there is a good reason for having multiple implementations. `IComparer<T>` is a great example, you might want to compare scores by the absolute score value, or the relative. So providing an abstraction is really useful.

Just applying interfaces to all classes is not a good idea, it will just make your code more complicated without any benefit. You might also discover that it can be difficult to provide a second implementation if the interface is not designed at the right abstraction level. This may result in adding properties or methods to objects that does not do anything or throws, just because they are required by a implemented interface. See for example [`IList<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ilist-1?view=net-6.0) where many of the implementer throw exceptions for some of the methods.

In the specific case of `IScore`, it *may* be useful if you have some need for additional score-classes. But in many cases I would argue that composition might be more useful, i.e.

```
public class MyNamedScore{
    public string Name {get;}
    public ScoreEntity Score {get;}
}
```

Comment: And overuse of interfaces tends to lead to violations of LSP - because ultimately, poor abstractions (which this definitely is) lend themselves to poor implementations, and poor usages of those abstractions. And then you find yourself casting interfaces to concrete classes, and...